# Strange behaviour when executing query on Oracle with EclipseLink

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, eclipselink, named-query

I created a namedquery as follows:

```
SELECT o
FROM TableName1Entity o , TableName2Entity a
WHERE o.field1 = a.field4
AND a.field5 = :param1
```

That is converted to the following sql:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME1.FIELD1, TABLE_NAME1.FIELD2, TABLE_NAME1.FIELD3
FROM TABLE_NAME2 t0, TABLE_NAME1 t1
WHERE ((t0.FIELD4 = t1.FIELD1)
AND (t0.FIELD5 = ?));
```

And it returns `ORA-00904: "TABLE_NAME1"."FIELD3": invalid identifier`

But it works when I manually modify as follows: (they all work as expected)

```
SELECT t1.FIELD1, t1.FIELD2, t1.FIELD3
FROM TABLE_NAME2 t0, TABLE_NAME1 t1
WHERE ((t0.FIELD4 = t1.FIELD1)
AND (t0.FIELD5 = ?));

SELECT TABLE_NAME1.FIELD1, TABLE_NAME1.FIELD2, TABLE_NAME1.FIELD3
FROM TABLE_NAME2 t0, TABLE_NAME1
WHERE ((t0.FIELD4 = TABLE_NAME1.FIELD1)
AND (t0.FIELD5 = ?));

SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3
FROM TABLE_NAME2 t0, TABLE_NAME1 t1
WHERE ((t0.FIELD4 = t1.FIELD1) AND (t0.FIELD5 = ?));

SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3
FROM TABLE_NAME2 t0, TABLE_NAME1
WHERE ((t0.FIELD4 = TABLE_NAME1.FIELD1)
AND (t0.FIELD5 = ?));
```

**PS.:** for security reasons, I cant give table or field names.

**The thing is:** when the table name is explicitly set along with a label to it, the query doesn't work.

> Please, don't give alternative solutions by changing the named query
>   because it should be fine as is and changing the named query is not an
>   option. unless it really has an error.

Comment: You did not show the named query; a named query belongs to the world of ORM and is written not in SQL (SQL having such an alias `label` for the table). Look at [what is a named query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517069/what-is-a-named-query)

Comment: and the JPA implementation is ? because conversion of a JPQL query into SQL is totally related to the implementation

Comment: JPA 1.0.2 with EclipseLink 1.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the version of EclipseLink from **1.1.1** to **2.0.0**

Answer (score 1):

What you've done it's called aliasing: the table `TABLE_NAME` must be referred as `label` in the select part of the query because it's how the table is named (and seen) by the rest of the query.

So you have to write something like:

```
SELECT label.FIELD_NAME FROM TABLE_NAME label;
```

Comment: ok, but i don't have any control how the named query is converted. :/
the query is **automatically** converted just like the first example.